Connection between Beckhoff PLC and Linux with PyADS
I would like to connect my Beckhoff CX5230 (Win10) to a Linux PC via PyADS. A topic that has been discussed here several times, but no solution has worked for me so far.
Beckhoff PLC Routing on Linux
Pyads connection refused with Beckhoff running Twincat 3
read and write variables in the PLC (beckhoff CX9020) with python pyads module
First, I created a route on the PLC from my Linux:
import pyads

SENDER_AMS = '5.97.120.143.1.1'
PLC_IP = '192.168.0.1'
PLC_USERNAME = 'Administrator'
PLC_PASSWORD = '1'
ROUTE_NAME = 'RouteToPC'
HOSTNAME = '192.168.0.1'

pyads.open_port()
pyads.set_local_address(SENDER_AMS)
pyads.add_route_to_plc(SENDER_AMS, HOSTNAME, PLC_IP, PLC_USERNAME, PLC_PASSWORD, route_name=ROUTE_NAME)
pyads.close_port()

That has worked well enough so far. I connected a monitor to the Beckhoff and saw that a new route had been created.
I was also able to establish a ping from the PLC to the PC and from the PC to the PLC. I therefore assume that the IP addresses are correct and the connection is established.
Next, I try to establish a route from my PC to the PLC:
import pyads

TARGET_AMS_ID = '5.97.120.143.1.1'
PLC_IP = '192.168.0.1'

plc = pyads.Connection(TARGET_AMS_ID, pyads.PORT_TC3PLC1, PLC_IP)
plc.open()
print(f"Connected?: {plc.is_open}")
print(f"Local Address? : {plc.get_local_address()}")
print(plc.read_state())

When I run the script, the following error occurs:
2024-06-12T17:28:09+0000 Info: Connected to 192.168.0.1
Connected?: True
Local Address? : <AmsAddress 192.168.0.253.1.1:30000>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyads_test.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(plc.read_state())
  File "/home/builder/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyads/connection.py", line 237, in read_state
    return adsSyncReadStateReqEx(self._port, self._adr)
  File "/home/builder/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyads/pyads_ex.py", line 510, in adsSyncReadStateReqEx
    raise ADSError(error_code)
pyads.pyads_ex.ADSError: ADSError: timeout elapsed (1861).
2024-06-12T17:28:14+0000 Info: connection closed by remote

I also tried these instructions here and created the route manually:
https://github.com/stlehmann/pyads/issues/281#issuecomment-956370290
Still have a "connection closed by remote" error:
pyads.open_port()
CLIENT_AMS_NET_ID = "192.168.0.253.1.1"
pyads.set_local_address(CLIENT_AMS_NET_ID)
pyads.close_port()
TARGET_AMS_ID = "5.97.120.143.1.1"
TARGET_PC_ID = "192.168.0.1"

plc = pyads.Connection(TARGET_AMS_ID, pyads.PORT_TC3PLC1, TARGET_PC_ID)
plc.open()
plc.write_by_name("GVL.P1", True)
exit()

builder@user:~$ python3 pyads_test.py
2024-06-18T08:49:10+0000 Info: Connected to 192.168.0.1
2024-06-18T08:49:10+0000 Info: connection closed by remote


port 851 is the port twincat port your PLC is running on, this is different to the ADS port

when trying to connect to the PLC (in your second example) the sender AMS should now be the AMS address of the PLC, not the Linux PC.
https://pyads.readthedocs.io/en/latest/documentation/routing.html#creating-routes-on-linux

Did I understand correctly that there are two separate AMS addresses, one from the PLC and one from the Linux PC? I have read out the AMS from the Beckhoff under Router > Edit Routes. I thought the AMS must be the same for both? How can I find out the AMS of my Linux or do I have to set one myself?

the AMS is different for both, you have to set it on the Linux PC, this is what the fucntionset_local_address does, you should set this address different to the ne the PLC has.

In my example, the SENDER_AMS/ TARGET_AMS = '5.97.120.143.1.1' is the AMSNetID of my Beckhoff PLC. This should therefore be correct.

Here is how I solved this problem, I wanted to connect to a CX7000 that is connected to an EL3443 terminal for energy monitoring.
In my case FB was already provided by Beckhoff to deal with the EL3443.
First you have to make sure that there is a running program on your PLC with the correct ADS port, this can be set up after you write your Structured Text, usually though it is pyads.PORT_TC3PLC1 = 851.
also make sure that you the routing table on your PLC has the rout to your linux device, you can set this in TwinCat or pyads >> see the relevant docs.
CLIENT_NETID =   # Your client's AMS Net ID
TARGET_IP =  # Target device IP
TARGET_NETID =  # Target device AMS Net ID

then you are good to go and make the connection from your linux machine
plc = pyads.Connection(TARGET_NETID, PLC_PORT, TARGET_IP)
plc.open()
print(plc.read_state())
plc.close()

